# Webform submissions

Tags: 7, webforms

I'd like to get the submission information from [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), I checked the API but it's can't get me the data I need. The main goal would be to get every submission in a xml/json/array so I could get work done with the data. Anyone done this before?

Also I'd like to point out that I know I could read it out of the database directly, but it would look definitely nicer with API if it can be done with it.

Comment: Would you mind if the data was exported as Excel format?

Comment: It's not about exporting data, but working with it realtime in another module :)

Comment: Ahh i see okay. well im sure you have seen the results section of the webform node which is clearly what you're not looking for :p

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just intercept the submission by a adding a a custom submit function with hook_form_alter, a la $form['#submit'][] = 'yourModule_yourForm_submit'; ?
Here I add it to the end of the submit functions array, but you can also put it first with array_unshift. There you can grab the values before they go in the db and do as you please with them.

Answer (score 0):

There's a module [webform_mysql_views](http://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) that exposes webform submissions to mysql views and combined with the data module you can expose them to views.

Als have a look at [#680386: Views integration for the webform_submitted_data table](http://drupal.org/node/680386)

Comment: webform_mysql_views module is only for 6.x not for 7.x :(

Comment: Put the port is almost complete, see [Webform MySQL Views for Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1089598)

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is [webform_get_submissions](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21includes%21webform.submissions.inc/function/webform_get_submissions/7). Here is a sample usage:

```
$submissions = @webform_get_submissions(array('nid'=>97));
foreach ($submissions as $submission {
  dpm($submission);
}
```

(Obviously, this is only for test and works if you have the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) installed.